# How to continue analysis pipeline?

Tags: regression, correlation, multivariate-analysis, trend

I have been working an a pipeline to analyze product parameters of a manufacturing process (e.g. different diameters, heights and color data) for quite a while now and it seems like I have hit a wall.

In the beginning I worked through a few time series analysis books and implemented the usual methods. I first tested for stationarity with both the ADF und KPSS tests and differenced the measurements to remove the trends in the data. I was mainly interested in whether I am able to predict future values to see if and when a parameter might be out of spec. This is why I implemented a VAR model with some of my parameters that were supposed to be correlated after calculating the cross-correlation, the Pearson, Kendall and Spearman coefficients as well as the granger causality.

The model itself was moderately successful and was able to predict the more regular parameters but failed for the more irregular measurements. After checking the correlations for the residuals I came to the conclusion that some explanatory variables were missing. Since all measurements are physical properties of an object and not the actual parameters of the manufactoring process this was sort of expected.

This is why I stopped any attempt at modeling the data through a VAR process and started to work on a more simple trend analysis. First I fit a trend using lowess since that resulted in a smooth and good enough approximation of the data and removed the large oscillations. To get a meaningful extension of the trend now I computed the derivative of the trend, averaged the last n derivatives and generated the values for a straight line with the just calculated slope. While this results in values that probably have a statistical meaning and are quite useful, I am not satisfied with this approach since it seems too basic.

Are there any obvious methods I am missing to further analyze the data? What more can I do with the calculated trends?

EDIT: I should probably also mention that my data consists of about 1 million data points per measurement in an 8h timespan with non uniform sampling.